# Regex ignore if exist and continue

Tags: php, regex

I'm using regex with php 
In these two example I would match TO MATCH

Example 1:

```
Nom: Mr TO MATCH
```

Example 2:

```
Nom: Mme TO MATCH
```

Example 3:

```
Nom: TO MATCH
```

I'm using Regex:

```
/Nom:\s+(?:Mr|Mme)\s+(.*)/ui
```

It works fine only for examples 1 and 2 but no for the 3rd one

How to tell Regex ignore Mr or Mme if exist and continue ?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your non-capturing group optional; changing `+` to `*` after the token `\s`.

```
Nom:\s+(?:Mr|Mme)?\s*(.*)
```

Or you can exclude the second `\s` and execute [**`trim()`**](http://php.net/trim) on your returned match result.

```
Nom:\s+(?:Mr|Mme)?(.*)
```